# Django: MySQL queries run really slowly, but are fast when run directly against database (not through Django)

Tags: mysql, django

I'm building a Django app with some pretty straightforward queries. When I run it locally the performance is pretty poor: DebugToolbar reports `4119.00 ms (6 queries)` which is obviously pretty bad. The longest-running query is this one:

Django `views.py` code:

```
reviews = list(Review.objects.select_related('band', 'record', 'label').order_by('-date_posted')[:12])
```

Outputted SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `reviews` 
INNER JOIN `bands` ON (`reviews`.`band_id` = `bands`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `records` ON (`reviews`.`record_id` = `records`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `label` ON (`reviews`.`label_id` = `label`.`id`) 
ORDER BY `reviews`.`date_posted` DESC 
LIMIT 12
```

Now obviously there's a few joins there, but my tables are properly indexed. When I run that query in phpMyAdmin I get `Query took 0.0241 sec`, but in DebugToolbar I see `1838.00 ms`. The other 5 queries are similarly sluggish, but run normally when queried directly.

I'm running Django on Windows and using MySQL (WAMP server). Can anyone think of any reason why Django's own queries could be so slow?

Comment: How much data is in each row?  Do you have a lot of BLOBS/TEXT fields?

Comment: Here's the row counts: `bands`: 2,544, `records`: 3,363, `reviews`: 3,516, `label`: 1,116. One `text` field in `reviews`, that's it.

Comment: You might want to try to change your query to limit the fields you're getting.  Try to see if select `reviews`.`band_id` from `reviews` ..... eliminates some of the discepency

Comment: That reduces the time a little. I've been playing around and somehow managed to get phpMyAdmin to return the same times for queries as Django, although this just means they're slower. It looks like the join on `bands` is the killer (despite indexes), according to the `EXPLAIN` I ran. Will keep digging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you are using the same database to do the comparisons.  If one has a small amount of data, and the other is huge, the timings will change.  This sounds like a silly thing to point out, but simpler mistakes have been made.
2. In Django, set `DEBUG=False`, so that Django won't store and trace the queries, which could add overhead.  I wouldn't expect it to add as much as you're seeing, but you need to make the environment realistic.

Comment: Yep, definitely the same (local) database. Tried setting `DEBUG=False`, although this disables DebugToolbar so hard to see the database response time. Let me turn off view caching as well and see if that helps measure things...

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really late but it might help if someone else is looking for a solution. I was facing the same issue on Windows but it got resolved when I disabled caching.

Comment: how did you disable caching?